# compile error when making functor a class member function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl, functor

I have a functor which i want to use with sort() the container in question has the type

```
std::list<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>>
```

This container is a temporary initialized in one of class GameBoard's functions.

the functor has the declaration

```
bool GameBoard::SortMoveList(std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> left, 
                             std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> right)
```

I get the compile error when i use the functor as follows:

```
moveList.sort(&GameBoard::SortMoveList);
```

Error:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\list(1324): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\list(1394) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::list<_Ty>::merge<_Pr3>(std::list<_Ty> &,_Pr3)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::pair<unsigned int,unsigned int>,
1>              _Pr3=bool (__thiscall GameBoard::* )(std::pair<unsigned int,unsigned int>,std::pair<unsigned int,unsigned int>)
1>          ]
1>          GameBoard.cpp(341) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::list<_Ty>::sort<bool(__thiscall GameBoard::* )(std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>,std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>)>(_Pr3)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::pair<unsigned int,unsigned int>,
1>              _Ty1=unsigned int,
1>              _Ty2=unsigned int,
1>              _Pr3=bool (__thiscall GameBoard::* )(std::pair<unsigned int,unsigned int>,std::pair<unsigned int,unsigned int>)
1>          ]
```

Any idea whats going wrong here?
The functor needs to access the class's private data, so i made it a member fn. If its not a member fn, it compiles fine. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Note, this is not a functor, this is simply a function!

Comment: What's the code where you try to use the sort function?

Comment: @Tim the code is moveList.sort(&GameBoard::SortMoveList); Its listed in the question right above the error.

Comment: A functor is a *class*, not a function. You can make it a nested class and/or a friend.

Comment: Is this the CS280 assignment? If so, it needs to be marked as homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A functor is a an **object** that behaves like a function.

This means you need to define a class that defines the operator()

Example:

```
class GameBoardMoveListSorter
{
    bool operator()(std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> const& left, 
                    std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> const& right) const
    {
        return left.first < right.first; // or whatever your strict weak ordering is.
    }
};

/// STUFF

moveList.sort(GameBoardMoveListSorter());
```

### Edit Based on Comment:

Comments from others please:

I though the new standard gave inner classes accesses to the enclosing classes private members. But having just re-read the standard that does not seem to be the wording I am seeing (the behavior of the compiler seems to allow accesses (though I know the conformance in this area has always been weak)).

#### Section 9.7 Paragraph 4

> Like a member function, a friend function (11.4) defined within a nested class is in the lexical scope of that class; it obeys the same rules for name binding as a static member function of that class (9.4), **but it has no special access rights to members of an enclosing class**.

Based on the above section of the manual. The inner class must be a friend class to accesses the private members of the outer class.

Note. Unlike java there is no implied parent relationship between inner and outer class. Thus the inner class must have an explicit reference to an outer class object to access its members.

```
#include <memory>

class Chess
{
    private:
        int     board[8][8];


        class GameBoardMoveListSorter
        {
            GameBoardMoveListSorter(Chess& p)
                : parent(p)
            {}

            bool operator()(std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> const& left,
                            std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> const& right) const
            {
                int val = parent.board[0][0] + parent.board[7][7];
                return left.first + val < right.first - val; // or whatever your strict weak ordering is.
            }

            Chess&      parent;
        };
        // I believe that it must be a friend to access private members.
        friend class GameBoardMoveListSorter;

    public:
        void makeMove()
        {
             std::list<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> >  moveList(/*Generate Moves*/);

             moveList.sort(GameBoardMoveListSorter(*this));
             // Do something with the move list.
        }
};
```

Comment: @Martin The question is where do I define this class if I need access to private methods and data of the GameBoard class?

Comment: @Martin, Thanks for the additional explanation. One last question: if we maintain a pointer to the Chess class, would it be better to use a friend class? Why/Why not?

Comment: @aCuria: One more update. It needs to be a friend (see update).

Comment: @Martin 1) If we are making the functor a friend, is there a reason to define class GameBoardMoveListSorter inside class chess? 2) Will making the overloaded operator()() a friend of chess suffice? Sorry for the multiple questions, my reference books don't really talk about this in any detail.

Comment: I tested making operator()() a friend. It compiles and runs fine.

Comment: You could alternatively pass in "board" rather than "parent" in which case it gets the access or even just pass in "val".

Comment: @CashCow: That works for simple examples. But in class with a lot of members this becomes a wiring mess. In this situation it may be worth passing an object reference and a member function pointer and initiating a callback to the class so that it has access to all members then putting the logic in a single location.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a member function in this way, as sort() has no notion of the object that it needs to be called upon. As you are in MSVC10, the easiest solution is a lambda.

```
std::sort(..., [&, this] -> bool (std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> left, std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> right) {
        return this->SortMoveList(left, right);
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I have never used lambda functions before, will they work in gcc/borland? Btw, visual studio complains about the syntax when I replace calls to sort() with the above code...

Comment: I found the problem, the syntax posted is slightly wrong. correct syntax is:moveList.sort( [&, this] (std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> left, std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> right) -> bool  
 {
        return this->SortMoveList(left, right);
 });

Comment: @aCuria: They may work in GCC if you have a recent version, it's unlikely that Borland has any versions recent enough. And yes, I posted some quick pseudocode for a call to std::sort, I don't know what your moveList type is or what the member function takes.

Comment: I know its quick pseudocode. I just posted the correct syntax for anyone who finds this in the future =) +1

Answer (score 1):

You could use that function together with boost::bind.

```
moveList.sort(boost::bind(&GameBoard::SortMoveList, this, _1, _2 ) );
```

If your implementation does not require the "this" then (i.e. it does not consult any class members to work out the comparison) then do not make it a class member function (not even a static one).

Note: for `boost::bind` you might replace with `std::bind` or `std::tr1::bind` dependent on what VC10 comes with and that should work.

Comment: It needs to call class methods and access class data in order to work.

Comment: Then this solution should work. VC10 comes with std::bind or std::tr1::bind which you can use instead of boost::bind here.